# Joining and rotating several kitchen doors

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make my kitchen in Blender, and because I have so many single meshes I would like to join them. But I also want to be able to open the dors, one at a time (hope you understand- I am Danish and not very good at English).
I have tried the Pivot Point, but I cannot make it work the way I want.
Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Join all the meshes you don't want to animate, like floors and walls, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

About the doors: Keep them as separate objects. You can parent them to the house object (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Object*) so that when you'll move the house on your scene they will follow.

You can't use the *Pivot Point* of the *3D View* to animate them, because it's not taken into account in animations, so come back to *Median Point* for example. You have to use bones, or, even simpler, use origin point:

In *Edit* mode Select the face where you want the rotation axis to be (ie hinge of the door), press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, go back in *Object* mode and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor*. Now the pivot point will be correct.

Comment: I think you might also have to mention parenting ... maybe not..

Comment: you mean parenting the doors to the house?

Comment: ..or the doors to the cupboards.. maybe not, they're probably not going to move.. but it's just such standard practice..

Comment: ok, edited  ;)  but we don't know enough about his object

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It helped a lot and it works.
I started with some windows at one of the walls and those I parented to the wall.
Next I will make the kitchen and parent the doors to the cupbords